# QuerySet django . How to write a function correctly to make tests pass

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, pytest

how returns in tree_downwards the root organization with the requested org_id and all its children at any nesting level and returns in tree_upwords the root organization with the requested org_id and all its parents at any nesting level  to make tests pas???
I will only be able to return either the parents or the organization itself

models.py

```
class OrganizationQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def tree_downwards(self, root_id):
    """
    :type root_org_id: int
    """
        return self.filter(???)

    def tree_upwards(self, child_id):
    """
    :type child_org_id: int
    """
        return self.filter(???)


class Organization(models.Model):
    objects = OrganizationQuerySet.as_manager()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=False, null=False)
    parent = models.ForeignKey(
    "self", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT
)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ["name"]
        verbose_name = "organization"

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

tests.py

```
def test_get_tree_downwards_cluster(make_organization):
    org_1 = make_organization()
    org_2 = make_organization(parent=org_1)
    children = Organization.objects.tree_downwards(org_1.id)
    assert org_1 in children
    assert org_2 in children

def test_get_parents_chain(make_organization):
    org_1 = make_organization()
    org_2 = make_organization(parent=org_1)
    org_3 = make_organization(parent=org_2)
    parents = Organization.objects.tree_upwards(org_3.id)
    assert org_1 in parents
    assert org_2 in parents
    assert org_3 in parents
```

Answer (score 1):

Does it have to be a QuerySet? I would implement it as follows:

```
from django.db import models


class Organization(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=1000, blank=False, null=False)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT, related_name='children')

    class Meta:
        ordering = {'name'}
        verbose_name = 'organization'

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    @property
    def tree_upward(self):
        result = [self]
        if self.parent:
            result += self.parent.tree_upward
        return result

    @property
    def tree_downward(self):
        result = [self]
        for child in self.children.all():
            result += child.tree_downward
        return result
```

Comment: sorry, but it should be QuerySet

Comment: I think that the class interface @physicalattraction set up for you is great. You can additionally construct your own query from his functions by filtering the parents ids.

Answer (score 1):

In the answer from @physicalattraction you get a very nice interface for the `Organization` model. If you really need to return a QuerySet, you could "cast" the list into a QuerySet like this:

```py
class Organization(models.Model):
    # other code

    @classmethod
    def _cast_to_queryset(cls,list):
        '''method to cast list of objects into queryset'''
        castlist = [rec.id for rec in list]
        queryset = cls.objects.filter(id__in=castlist)
        return queryset

    @property
    def tree_upward(self):
        result = [self]
        if self.parent:
            result += self.parent.tree_upward
        return Organization._cast_to_queryset(result) # <-- cast to queryset

    @property
    def tree_downward(self):
        result = [self]
        for child in self.children.all():
            result += child.tree_downward
        return Organization._cast_to_queryset(result) # <-- cast to queryset
```

I think this would work nicely and retain the nice interface that @physicalattraction set up for you in his answer.